# Simple Factory Pattern Demo

Tags: php, object-oriented

I am trying to create a simple factory pattern demo in PHP. I am not sure if my codes are the best practice. It seems that I have some duplicated codes but I am not sure how to improve it. Basically, I want to create 3 types of accounts (basic, premium and vip). Please advise. Thanks a lot.

abstract class

```
abstract class User {

    function __construct() {
        $this->db= new Database('mysql','localhost','mvcdb','root','');
    }

    abstract function checkUser();

    function showAccountCredit(){
        return $this->credits;
    }
    function getUserName(){
        return $this->username;
    }


}
```

I have 3 different user account types:

Basic Account

```
class BasicUser extends User {

    function __construct($username) {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->username=$username;
        $this->credit='10';
        $this->accountType='Basic Account';

        $data=$this->checkUser();

        if(!empty($data)){
            echo 'The username: '.$this->username.' already exists<br>';
            return false;
        }

        $array=array('username'=>$this->username, 'password'=>'password','credit'=> $this->credit,'accountType'=>$this->accountType);
        $this->db->insert('user',$array);

    }


     function checkUser(){

        $array=array(':username'=>$this->username);
        $results=$this->db->select('SELECT * FROM USER WHERE username=:username',$array);
        if(!empty($results)){
        $this->credit=$results[0]['credit'];
        $this->accountType=$results[0]['accountType'];
        }

        return $results;

    }

    function showAccountCredit() {
        echo 'Username: '.$this->username.'<br>';
        echo 'Account Credit: '.$this->credit.'<br>';
        echo 'Account Type: '.$this->accountType;
    }

}
```

Premium Account

```
class PremiumUser extends User {

    function __construct($username) {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->username=$username;
        $this->credit='100';
        $this->accountType='Premium Account';

        $data=$this->checkUser();

        if(!empty($data)){
            echo 'The username: '.$this->username.' already exists<br>';
            return false;
        }

        $array=array('username'=>$this->username, 'password'=>'password','credit'=> $this-                   >credit,'accountType'=>$this->accountType);
        $this->db->insert('user',$array);

    }


     function checkUser(){

        $array=array(':username'=>$this->username);
        $results=$this->db->select('SELECT * FROM USER WHERE username=:username',$array);
        if(!empty($results)){
        $this->credit=$results[0]['credit'];
        $this->accountType=$results[0]['accountType'];
        }

        return $results;

    }

    function showAccountCredit() {
        echo 'Username: '.$this->username.'<br>';
        echo 'Account Credit: '.$this->credit.'<br>';
        echo 'Account Type: '.$this->accountType.'<br>';
    }

}
```

VIP account:

```
class VipUser extends User {

    function __construct($username) {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->username=$username;
        $this->credit='1000';
        $this->accountType='VIP Account';

        $data=$this->checkUser();

        if(!empty($data)){
            echo 'The username: '.$this->username.' already exists<br>';
            return false;
        }

        $array=array('username'=>$this->username, 'password'=>'password','credit'=> $this->credit,'accountType'=>$this->accountType);
        $this->db->insert('user',$array);

    }


     function checkUser(){

        $array=array(':username'=>$this->username);
        $results=$this->db->select('SELECT * FROM USER WHERE username=:username',$array);
        if(!empty($results)){
        $this->credit=$results[0]['credit'];
        $this->accountType=$results[0]['accountType'];
        }

        return $results;

    }

    function showAccountCredit() {
        echo 'Username: '.$this->username.'<br>';
        echo 'Account Credit: '.$this->credit.'<br>';
        echo 'Account Type: '.$this->accountType;
    }

}
```

UserFactory class

```
class UserFactory {

    static function create($username,$accountType){

        $accountType = strtolower($accountType);

        switch($accountType){
        case 'basic': return new BasicUser($username);
        case 'premium':return new PremiumUser($username);
        case 'vip': return new VipUser($username);
        default :return new BasicUser($username);
        }
    }
```

index.php

```
$user1= UserFactory::create('Jerry', 'Vip');
$user1->showAccountCredit();


$user2= UserFactory::create('Bob', 'Basic');
$user2->showAccountCredit();


$user3= UserFactory::create('Betty', 'premium');
$user3->showAccountCredit();
```

Answer (score 2):

This question is pretty old, but I have a few things to add to showerhead's answer

---

**new in a constructor**

- Creating an object in a constructor is an antipattern.  It immediately introduces very tight coupling, and it makes testing absolutely impossible.
- You're needlessly creating database connections over and over again.
- A User class' only business is to model a User.  It has no business creating database connections.

What you should do instead is pass the database connection into the user object.  (Or, if it's strictly a model, you might let some other type of object handle database interaction and let the User class essentially be for data storage/organisation.)

**echoing in a constructor**

A class should almost never output directly (unless the goal of the class is to handle rendering).  What if you wanted to output a different message in a certain situation?  What if you want to handle the error silently?  It restricts you to handling things in one very specific way.

Instead, make use of return values or exceptions.

**returning in a constructor**

Returning a value in a constructor does not work.  Personally, I believe it should be a syntax error, but PHP has chosen to just ignore it.

Where would the return value go?  The variable receiving the instance?  But then the reference to the object is lost.  If you ever find yourself returning false in a constructor, it's probably a sign that exceptions should be used.

**showAccountCredit**

Nothing is being shown.  Perhaps it should be `getAccountCredit`.

**What is the user class?**

Is it a model?  Is it a controller?  Is it a data persistence layer?  It looks like a model to me, in which case whether or not it should be responsible for creating users is debatable.

Answer (score 1):

**Switch Statement**

Inside your `UserFactory::create()` method I would do away with the "basic" case as it is the same as default. You can continue passing 'basic' as an argument with no change if you wish, or just stop passing the second argument for basic users. No need to replicate functionality that already exists :)

**Edit:** For clarification, you may still define that case if you wish. I know some people like covering every case they will use, even if they end up duplicating it as the default. Personally I just prefer defining it once.

**Inheritance**

I'm not sure you understand inheritance correctly... All your other classes (child classes) inherit methods and properties from your User class (parent class). So if you take all those methods that are the same in every class and give it to your parent class, you wont have to override them in the child class unless something changes in them. So essentially each child class should only have a construct method because the other two methods are the same and should be in the User class.

Overriding a method is when you have a method defined in a parent class and then define that same method in the child class. The child method supercedes the parent method and then the only way to call the parent's version of that method would be to use the scope resolution operator `::` along with the class name followed by the method, so `parent::__construct()` as an example. This is useful if you have variables that change depending on the class but the rest of the functionality remains the same, or if you wish to add functionality to one class but not another.

So taking this knowledge the construct method in each child should resemble this...

```
function __construct($username) {
    $this->credit='1000';
    $this->accountType='VIP Account';
    parent::__construct();
}
```

And your construct method in your parent class should resemble this...

```
function __construct($username) {
    $this->db= new Database('mysql','localhost','mvcdb','root','');

    $this->username=$username;

    $data=$this->checkUser();
    if(!empty($data)){
        echo 'The username: '.$this->username.' already exists<br>';
        return false;
    }

    $array=array(
        'username'=>$this->username,
        'password'=>'password',
        'credit'=> $this->credit,'
        accountType'=>$this->accountType
    );//don't have to do this, I just find this cleaner, you can also check out PHP's compart() function
    $this->db->insert('user',$array);
}
```

**Defining Properties and Methods**

You never define your class properties, so all of them are public by default :O This may not be a big issue as I don't see any secure information being set, but you should still define them before you use them. These properties should be defined within the class but outside of any methods and should be located at the top of your class.

```
public $username;
//OR for a group
public
    $username,
    $credit = 100,
    $password
;
```

None of your child methods appear to be called correctly either. They are not defined as either public or private. I am assuming this and the last point is because this is a "demo" and you simply neglected to add them, but in case it isn't I'm pointing it out here.

```
public function __construct()
//OR
public static function create()
//OR
private function somePrivateFunc()
```

**Reusing Variables**

Instead of continuously checking `$results[0]etc...` just make `$results[0]` a variable. Makes it cleaner.

**Final Thoughts**

Hope this helps, don't use the factory method myself so I can't say whether you are using it correctly. But my suggestions should still be valid.